# SQL table valued function not giving correct value

Tags: sql-server

I have this function which I have created to get the total absents of an employee in a month. When I provide the parameters in the sql query body and execute the command it works perfectly fine but when I provide the values in parameters and execute the function it is returning 0 in all cases.
Here is my function. I think I am missing something like conversion or something but cannot get to the bottom of issue. Hope someone can help

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetAbsentCount]
 (
  @StartDate AS DATETIME,
  @EndDate DATETIME,
  @EmpCode INT
 )
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT SUM(Status) Absentss
    FROM ( 
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 
        IsOffDay = 1 AND PreviousDayTimeIn IS NULL AND PreviousDayTimeOut IS NULL AND NextDayTimeIn IS NULL AND NextDayTimeOut IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN IsOffDay = 1 AND (PreviousDayTimeIn IS NOT NULL OR PreviousDayTimeOut IS NOT NULL OR NextDayTimeIn IS NOT NULL OR NextDayTimeOut IS NOT NULL) THEN 0
        WHEN IsPublicHoliday = 1 AND PreviousDayTimeIn IS NULL AND PreviousDayTimeOut IS NULL AND NextDayTimeIn IS NULL AND NextDayTimeOut IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN IsPublicHoliday = 1 AND (PreviousDayTimeIn IS NOT NULL OR PreviousDayTimeOut IS NOT NULL OR NextDayTimeIn IS NOT NULL OR NextDayTimeOut IS NOT NULL) THEN 0
        WHEN TimeIn1 IS NULL AND TimeOut1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Status
    FROM
    (
      SELECT 
        [dbo].[fnIsOffDay](datename(dw,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @EmpCode) AS IsOffDay,
        [dbo].[fnIsPublicHoliday](CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @EmpCode) AS IsPublicHoliday,
        PreviousDayTimeIn    = [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](1,DATEADD(DD, -1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @EmpCode, 1),
        TimeIn1    = [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](1,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @EmpCode, 1),
        NextDayTimeIn    = [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](1,DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @EmpCode, 1),
        PreviousDayTimeOut   = CASE WHEN [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,DATEADD(DD, -1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @EmpCode, 2) IS NULL THEN [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,DATEADD(DD, -1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @EmpCode, 1)
                     ELSE [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,DATEADD(DD, -1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @EmpCode, 2) END,
        TimeOut1   = CASE WHEN [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @EmpCode, 2) IS NULL THEN [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @EmpCode, 1)
                     ELSE [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE), @EmpCode, 2) END,
        NextDayTimeOut   = CASE WHEN [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @EmpCode, 2) IS NULL THEN [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @EmpCode, 1)
                 ELSE [dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut](0,DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE)), @EmpCode, 2) END
      FROM [CalendarDates] 
      WHERE CAST(CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE) AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @StartDate
    )T
    )S
)


--SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnGetAbsentCount] ('2019-09-01', '2019-09-30', 17)
```

Cannot provide the sample data as it's quite large to handle so I hope someone can find out the issue by just analyzing the code.
Thanks

Comment: WHERE CAST(CAST(CalendarDate AS DATE) AS DATE) BETWEEN StartDate AND StartDate change it to BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate

Comment: You can't provide sample data? Looks like we just need a handful of columns from a single table. If possible, consider running a query that will return five or so rows with the relevant columns and include that here. And the code for functions `fnIsOffDay`, `fnIsPublicHoliday`, `fnGetTimeInOut`. Otherwise, this isn't a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The function on it's own tells us nothing. We need sample data, and expected results. Also, you have 10's of references to the scalar function `[dbo].[fnGetTimeInOut]`, which you've omitted from your post. I *hope* however, those scalar functions don't reference any tables, or they're going to be great as a performance killer.

Comment: There are many things less than ideal in here. Your where predicate seems to be the problem. But the formatting is enough to make me want to take out my eyeballs and pop them. You have column aliases but you switch back and forth on the style. Pick one and stick with it consistently. You are using shorthand for date functions which is challenging at best. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations The last three columns in your query could be simplified using ISNULL instead of a case expression and running the function twice.

Comment: You could also remove the outer query with the sum and just have the sum on the inner query. You are also casting CalendarDate to a date twice in your where clause. Once is sufficient. And man those scalar functions...